# Need to show a popup/Dialog on different activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog, popupwindow

I have an app that uses three Activities. I've created in the first one a Thread that checks the connection with the server and when the app cant reach the server it shows a Popup.

The thing is that when I go from the Activity1 to the Activity2 and I lose the connection, I'm getting a WindowManager$BadTokenException.

I've tried with PopupWindow and with AlertDialog but I have the same problem, I can't give them the current Activity.

Alert Dialog:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder1.setMessage("Se ha hecho el cierre diario, es necesario reiniciar la aplicación.");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                {
                    java.lang.System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
```

PopupWindow:

```
        final Activity context = Activity_Start.this;

        final boolean Reset = reset;

        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup_mensaje_error);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View popup_error = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mensaje_error, viewGroup, false);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        final PopupWindow popupW_error = new PopupWindow(context);
        popupW_error.setContentView(popup_error);
```

In both cases I have the same error and I'm almost 100% sure that is cause getApplicationContext() is no enough to get what the app needs.

Can someone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Use a DialogFragment and you could attach an detach to any activity you like

Comment: I think your error resides in "final Activity context = Activity_Start.this;" You shouldn't get the context like this

Comment: Raghunandan, how it works?

Klitos, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android documents suggests to use `getApplicationContext();`

but it will not work instead of that use your current activity while instantiating AlertDialog.Builder or AlertDialog or Dialog...

Try

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_Start.this);
```

instead of

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

And also use

```
final Context context = Activity_Start.this;
```

instead of

```
final Activity context = Activity_Start.this;
```

The dialog is tied to this particular activity, and not the entire application. Generally use Activity.this when creating objects whose scope is just the activity. Use Application context when you are creating objects whose scope is beyond the current activity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah Rajesh, I have that way, the problem is that the Thread started on Activity1 and if I'm working on Activity2 when the connection is lost, I don't know how to send to the Dialog the current Activity.

Comment: Did, but I'm getting the WindowManager$BadTokenException when calling the dialog from Activity2.

Comment: why are you calling activity's dialog from activity2? you can not do that.

Comment: That's my problem. The Thread is declarated in the first activity and the popup is supossed to be shown on any activity.

Comment: Then what can I do to have a proccess running in background that can show the message over any activity if neccessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87784/discussion-between-rajesh-jadav-and-oscar-rubio).